# Is an offset reliable and faster?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like so:

```
+-----------------+
|userid      pics |
|0           1000 |
|1           10   |
|...         ...  |
+-----------------+
```

Where 'pics' is the number of pics the guy has. And then I have a second table:

```
+----------------------+
|picid       uploaderid|
|0           0         |
|1           2         |
|...         ...       |
+----------------------+
```

What I do is iterate through uploaderid to retrieve all the pic id's of the images he/she uploaded. Would it be reliable to LIMIT to the amount of pics the person uploaded, and also would it be faster? Assume a large database.

Thanks.

Comment: You tell us, it all depends on what you're trying accomplish when limiting the number of pictures. If you're trying to retrieve all photos my a certain user ID then using LIMIT wouldn't work.

Comment: @NoahR That's why I asked - why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Okay. Let's assume you want to select all photos by Tom but you're using LIMIT in your MYSQL query. Tom has 200 photos but we don't know this using the LIMIT statement, so how would we select all his photos? SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5 would only retrieve 5 photos. If you wanted to retrieve all of Tom's photos you would use SELECT * FROM tbl; Of course you'd use a WHERE statement with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `limit` would be faster if the query required a full-table scan.  This would allow the full-table scan to stop after it has hit the last picture by a user.  In many cases, this could reduce the time by a factor of 2 or more.

However, you should have an index on `SecondTable(uploaderid)`.  With an index, using `limit` isn't going to improve performance because the index already knows where the last pic is by a user.

Comment: The normal approach would be to have an index.